# choosing a random number from a tuple + some numbers

Tags: python, random, tuples

I have a tuple of numbers, and I want to choose a random number from my tuple in addition with a certain number. For example:

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3)
```

and I have the number 4. I want to choose a random number from the numbers 1,2,3,4 (without changing the tuple of course).

I tried:

```
my_tp = (1, 2, 3)
a = random.choice(list(my_tp).append(4))
print(a)
```

I'm new to python. I tried converting the tuple to a list, and then performing the random function.
The code above didn't work. Got the error

> object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Would love some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `list.append` returns `none`

Once converting to a `list` as you have done, appending will modify that `list` but return `none` so that is the source of your `error`.

To get round that you can either convert the `tuple` to a `list` then `append 4` to it, then use `random.choice`, or in just one step, you can concatenate a list of `[4]` with the `+` operand.

This approach is much simpler:

```
import random

my_tuple = (1,2,3)
random.choice(list(my_tuple) + [4])
```

Hope this helps and clears some things up! :)

**Update:**

If you want to just randomly select from the tuple without the last item, then just `slice` the list with the normal syntax:

```
random.choice(list(my_tuple)[:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks. And If I want to perform subtraction? a simple '-' won't do it

Comment: what do you mean? here you aren't using addition, the `+` is concatenating the lists.

Comment: Yes. If the tuple is (1,2,3), and i want to subtract the number 3, and choose from a random number in (1,2)

Comment: Then just slice up to the last value with `list(my_tuple)[:-1]` :)

Answer (score 2):

The method `list.append` alters the provided list and returns `None`, which explains the exception you got. To get the desired result, you can implicitly use the `tuple.__add__` method, which will return a new tuple.

```
values = (1, 2, 3)
random.choice(values + (4,))
```

If you want to remove values in a concise-ish fashion, using a `set` might be appropriate.

```
values = {1, 2, 3}
random.choice(list(values - {3}))
```

Comment: Thanks. And If I want to perform subtraction? a simple '-' won't do it

Comment: @sheldonzy The only built-in which allows "subtraction" in this manner is `set`. I have added an option showing this usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3)
random.choice((*my_tuple, 4))
```

Where `(*my_tuple, 4)` creates a new tuple with the unpacked content of `my_tuple` and `4`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that that unpacking syntax is [new in Python 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: That was introduced with [python3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations), in September 2015. Not exactly what I would call new.